# Save canvas image to folder in project

Tags: javascript, c#, html5-canvas

I am trying to get the canvas image to be downloaded to a folder in the asp.net project instead of being downloaded locally to the user's machine.

The code below converts a table to a canvas image and places it into a hidden field

```
function ConvertToImage(btnExport) {
            html2canvas($("#tbl_email_sig")[0]).then(function (canvas) {
                var base64 = canvas.toDataURL();
                $("[id*=hfimagedata]").val(base64);
                __doPostBack(btnExport.name, "");
            });
            return false;
        }
```

The code below downloads the image locally

```
        string base64 = Request.Form[hfimagedata.UniqueID].Split(',')[1];
        byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);
        Response.Clear();
        Response.ContentType = "image/jpg";
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=yourimage.jpg");
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
        Response.End();
```

Comment: So you're asking how to write a file in C#? Did you look at the `File` class?

Comment: I did but I am unsure of what to do

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writeallbytes